# How to enable user_xattr in Mint Cinnamon?

Tags: fstab

I just installed [Netflix Desktop](http://www.compholio.com/netflix-desktop/) on my Cinnamon Mint, but I can't start it. When I run the program, I get the following message:

> It appears that you do not have extended file system attributes enabled. Please enable the user_xattr option for your filesystem and try again.

I tried to edit the `fstab` file as told in a couple different posts, but they don't work; I don't have a line that looks like this in my file:

```
UUID=94f7fc1e-fa27-4b24-99f3-4b461665a4a4       /       ext4    errors=remount-ro,user_xattr       0       1
```

And when I add it and restart, nothing changes.

Answer (score 4):

You need to leave your UUID for your hard drive in that modification. This UUID in the example is different than yours:

```
UUID=94f7fc1e-fa27-4b24-99f3-4b461665a4a4
```

An entry for your `/` should've already been present for your HDD.

If you're unsure what UUID your HDD has you can use the `blkid` command to get the UUIDs' for your HDDs.

#### Example

```
$ sudo blkid
/dev/sda1: UUID="1f2832de-ee34-461f-8fb1-cb86ffde8d44" TYPE="ext2" 
/dev/sda5: UUID="6qwe112-dGB3-vCp2-XibP-qsmE-nWbs-E123eJ" TYPE="LVM2_member" 
/dev/mapper/ubuntu-root: UUID="5b6417237-ab46-1234-11f9-81dcf2111129" TYPE="ext4" 
/dev/mapper/ubuntu-swap_1: UUID="5ab3q12h-26a7-85qw-12fd-57e7c95e2232" TYPE="swap"
```

Your `fstab` file may have a line like this:

```
/dev/mapper/ubuntu-root /               ext4    errors=remount-ro 0       1
```

You should change the options from this `errors=remount-ro` to this `errors=remount-ro,user_xattr`.

Comment: OK, I think the problem is that I am running it live off of a flash drive. Every time I restart, my changes to `fstab` are reversed. Is there any way I can get around that? Also, which one [these drives](http://pastebin.com/1WzJrjuF) is the one I should use? The flash drive name is IANSAN5653.

Comment: @Ian - yeah you should be able to change it. This one is likely the USB drive: `/dev/sdb1`. Give me a couple of minutes to look up how to do it, if it's possible.

Comment: @Ian - I would assume that Mint would be similar to Ubuntu: http://askubuntu.com/questions/48535/how-to-customize-the-ubuntu-live-cd

Comment: OK, [here](http://pastebin.com/fWAiHvWW) is my `fstab` file now. It works, but when I remount the drive I get this message: `mount: mount point /vfat does not exist`.

Comment: @Ian - it's likely that the file is dynamically rebuilt at boot/run each time. The directory `/vfat` doesn't exist. You'll have to pick a different directory that exists.

Comment: OK, I thought that was the drive type. What directory should it be?

Comment: @Ian - no the 3rd column is the type. Hard to say. It would have to be a directory that is present, yet is empty. I would look at `/mnt` if that exists to start.